# Java Deserialization issue in SPring MVC Project using AOP

Tags: java, spring, serialization

I am trying to deserialize an object, using simple code

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
Object sss = ois.readObject();
```

ois.readObject is throwing classNotFound Exception, even i have all the classes

when i dig further , i found that the deserilizer is looking for a class like

```
com.xy.services.bank.trans.bean.SampleBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee37d1aa
```

I have SampleBean in my project, but why the JVM is enahancing the bean, i am not able to figure out

can anyone give the clue what may be happening

Thank you

Comment: It is Spring that is enhancing the class, not the JVM.  And it will be doing that because of something in your code-base; e.g. annotations, XML configs, etc.  Clearly, it is wrong to persist a serialize an instance of an enhanced class, or pass it to another JVM.  Your problem is to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you serialized anything that was Injected by Spring, you have to understand that Spring actually injects Proxies, not the real object which is what you are seeing there.

On a related note, not sure what you are trying to do, but I would stay clear of serialized objects unless absolutely necessary.